# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_IO_Curl::authenticatedRequest()

Tags: php, github, google-api-php-client

When using the described in the Google Contacts API example [simple.php](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/branches/name-restructure/examples/contacts/simple.php?r=563), and the [Google API PHP Client from GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), version 1.0.4-beta, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_IO_Curl::authenticatedRequest()
```

However, when I change this line...

```
$val = $client_svc_contacts->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
```

...to...

```
$val = $client_svc_contacts->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($req);
```

...then it starts working again.

I am using version 1.0.4-beta unmodified except for the addition of the following line at the top of Client.php:

```
set_include_path(str_replace('/Google','',dirname(__FILE__)));
```

I recognize that simple.php was written for version 0.6, not v1+, but is the example just out of date compared to the version on GitHub? Or is there something wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/migration) that had the answer ...

> A new home for authenticatedRequest
>
> The authenticatedRequest method has been moved from the io classes to
>   the auth classes.

So it appears that replacing `getIo()` with `getAuth()` was the correct course of action.